# Page-tab: show overlay in iframe depending on Like

Tags: facebook, iframe, callback, tabs, facebook-like

I wanna add an overlay (already built the HTML 'n jQuery) to a custom iframe tab, that only shows if people haven't liked my client's page yet. Is this possible with the JS SDK? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

While this is better done server-side, you code use something like:

```
FB.api('/me/likes/PAGE_ID',function(response) {
    if( response.data ) {
        if( !isEmpty(response.data) )
            alert('You are a fan!');
        else
            alert('Not a fan!');
    } else {
        alert('ERROR!');
    }
});

// function to check for an empty object
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

*The code is taken from my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/).*

Comment: as far as I can work out this only works if a user has given permission to access his/her likes... Which is kind of self-defeating...

Comment: true and true! The `signed_request` is handled server-side, this is why you can know if the landing user is a fan or not even without authorizing your app.